# how to pass from GRID to PACK

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-entry

I already developed my GUI app (based on tkinter) using the pack method to show all widgets...
Now I want to create a '2d array' and show and get values from it.
here is a working solution based on grid. method that I want to convert to pack method.
any suggestion?

I couldn't include the 2 loops (rows and columns) with the pack method.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
root = Tk()
entries = []
def set_entries():
    for i in range(10):
        entries.append([])
        for j in range(10):
            entries[i].append(tk.Entry())

            entries[i][j].grid(row=i, column=j, sticky="nsew")
    tk.Button( text=" run", command=compute).grid(row=10,column=10)
def compute():
    print(entries[2][4].get())
set_entries()
root.mainloop()
button.tk.Button(text='run')
button.grid(row=10, column=10, sticky="nsew")
```

Comment: `grid` is the right choice for making a 2d array. It will be much more complicated using `pack`. Why do you want to do this with `pack`?

Comment: I already developed the whole code using pack ... is there a way to create a frame containing all cells of one column and then duplicate it (n rows) times to have a 2D array ? or also is therw a way to combine the two methods (pack and grid ) : it shows me an error when I tried to do it ...

Comment: Well if you are unwilling to change your main code to use grid then you can simply use a frame that is packed and inside that frame use grid. That said I normally only use pack for simple things like testing or setting up my a couple frames before applying all my other widgets. Personally I use `grid()` 95% of the time as I find it more useful than `pack()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend using `pack`, it's simply not designed to make a grid. It requires a separate frame for each row or for each column, and it's up to you to make sure the widgets are all the same size, which you don't need when using `grid`.

If you're already using `pack` in other parts of the program, create a frame just for the array and use `grid` for the widgets in the frame, and then use `pack` for the other parts of your program. There's nothing wrong with using both in a program, you just can't use both on widgets that have a common master.

Here's a contrived example, showing how you can use `pack` and `grid` in the same application:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
array_frame = tk.Frame(root)
toolbar = tk.Frame(root)

# use pack for the toolbar and array frame, grid inside the array frame
toolbar.pack(side="top", fill="x")
array_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

run_button = tk.Button(toolbar, text="Run")
run_button.pack(side="left")

entries = {}
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        entry = tk.Entry(array_frame)
        entry.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky="nsew")
        entries[(i,j)] = entry

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This seems very helpful !
I'll try to implement the idea in my application... Thanks a lot.